# Python one-liner with if

Tags: python, list

How to make this code into a one-liner?
The list contains only 0 and 1

```
val = 0
for item in list:
    if item == 0:
       val += 1
```

Comment: What have **you** tried so far?

Comment: What does `list` contain?

Comment: I would read up on generator expressions, figure out how to write one that will return an iterable of the values you want to add to `val`, then look for a convenient way to add the contents of an iterable of integers.

Comment: Look into the `sum()` function and conditionals in generators.

Comment: The list contains only 0 and 1.

Comment: You can also take advantage of the fact that booleans can be treated as numbers: `True == 1 and False == 0`

Comment: @LiamBarmaimon If that's true, just use the `sum()` function all by itself.

Comment: `sum(map(lambda a: a==0, lst))`

Comment: BTW, don't use `list` as a variable name, since it's the name of a built-in function/class.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest you:

```
val = list.count(0)
```

Comment: Yes, very concise solution.

Comment: And surprisingly, it's the faster one.  (just simple perf. testing...)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `sum()` function along with a generator expression.

```
val = sum(1 - item for item in list)
```

or

```
val = sum(0 == item for item in list)
```

or you can use a conditional in the generator

```
val = sum(1 for item in list if item == 0)
```

Comment: Personally I'd prefer `sum(1 for item in list if item == 0)` - no point in emitting a bunch of 0s when you know you'll be summing anyway, and I've never liked treating booleans as integer values - but tastes vary there.

Comment: That's incorrect syntax, see my edit for the correct way to write it.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Time for another cup of coffee, I know better than that.

Comment: `sum(1 for x in L if not x)`   Alternatively,    maybe?

Comment: @DanielHao Possible, but I dislike it.

Comment: @DanielHao - yeah, that'd work too. Or just `sum(not x for x in L)` if you're ok with summing booleans to an integer. For my tastes the explicit comparison is clearer but I don't think there's a practical difference.

Comment: @DanielHao In general I don't like treating numbers as booleans unless it's in a context where the zero/nonzero distinction represents some kind of false/true dichotomy.

Comment: It's prob. more about `style` or `taste` than Pythonic`?  I saw many Open Source package using similar syntax.  Thanks @Bamar for elaborating it more...

Comment: Yes, it's very much a personal decision.